# Jolt - Transform from same key that can have string or an object value

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am trying to transform an input data where the same key-value could be string or object. But not able to figure out the correct transformation. Could someone please help. Thanks!

Input

```json
[
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "location": {
      "value": "loc-123"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "location": {
      "value": "loc-789"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "id3",
    "location": "loc-666"
  }
]
```

Desired output:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "loc": "loc-123"
  },
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "loc": "loc-789"
  },
  {
    "id": "id3",
    "loc": "loc-666"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following transformation

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&", // generates array-wise([ ]) results after going one (&1) level up 
                       // the tree to reach the level of indexes within the array
        "*ation": {
          "value": "[&2].&(1,1)",// increments +1 more level compared to the upper one
          "*": { // else case
            "@1": "[&3].&(2,1)"  // [&3]:increments +1 more level compared to the upper one
                                 // &(2,1):replicates the 1st piece represented 
                                 // by asterisk in "*ation" after going 2 levels up
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the **demo** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: Thanks Barbaros. What if there are multiple values inside location object in addition to value field as well. Is there a generic way to perform this transformation without explicitely mapping every attribute inside the location object. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: @ayan_2587 well but how kind of result do you wanna get? Since, you want only one attribute with unique name `loc` per each object,and logic for the last object, which probably keep the same logic of uniquely naming , is different than the others